# Equivalence class property

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $R\subset A^2$ be an equivalence relation. Prove that $b \in [a] \implies [a]=[b]$.

$\textbf{Proof}$

Suppose that $b \in [a]$. By definition of equivalence class our hypothesis is equivalent to $bRa$, and by the symmetric property of $R$ we have that $bRa$ if and only if $aRb$, but by the transitive property of $R$ we have that $bRa$ and $aRb$ is the case if and only if $bRb$. By definition of equivalence class we know that $bRb$ is equivalent to $b \in [b]$. Therefore, $b \in [a]$ if and only if $b\in [b]$ and by the axiom of extensionality we conclude that $[a]=[b]$. Q.E.D.

I want to know if my proof is correct, can anyone help me please? Thank you so much

Comment: Seems like a fine proof.

Comment: You already know that $b\in[b]$. You know from your hypothesis that $a$ and $b$ are equivalent. If you show that any element equivalent to $a$ is equivalent to $b$, you get that $[a]\subset [b]$. Similarly, showing that any element equivalent to $b$ is equivalent to $a$ shows $[b]\subset [a]$.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean a true thing, but "$bRa$ and $aRb$ is the case if and only if $bRb$" is false as stated. By reflexivity, $bRb$ is always true, so there's no need to find a proof for that.

More seriously, your use of the axiom of extensionality is invalid. If you had proved that for all $c$ it is true that $c\in[a]$ if and only if $c\in[b]$, then that would be a correct use; but you only have $b\in[a]$ if and only if $b\in[b]$ for the one specific element $b$.

Comment: And if I add at the begining of my proof "Let $b$ be an arbitrary element of $A$" my use of the axiom of extensionality would be correct?

Comment: No, because that $b$ is the same $b$ that defines $[b]$. By way of analogy, let $b$ be an integer and consider the dubious assertion $\Bbb Z = \{b\}$. You can easily prove that $b\in\Bbb Z$ if and only if $b\in\{b\}$, since both statements are true. But the axiom of extensionality does not then imply that $\Bbb Z = \{b\}$, and adding the words "Let $b$ be an arbitrary integer" doesn't change that.